# Phpmyadmin table disappears, but website reads it perfectly

Tags: mysql, database

When I log into phpmyadmin, it only shows the information_schema. I have only one table that has been showing perfectly, but one day it decided not to show up. My website reads all the information in the database just fine, I just can't see it in phpmyadmin. Once I restarted the mysql server and it popped back up. Now when I try to restart it, it doesn't show anymore. How can I solve this??

Comment: Have you checked for permissions issues ? Do you have some views defined by a user that does not exist anymore ?

Comment: When I look for my database I can't even see it, so can't add permissions to it. It was working fine when I logged off one day, and when I came back it had disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation would be that you are no longer logging in as a valid user through phpMyAdmin. From the phpMyAdmin main page, look to the right side; under "Database server" it should tell you what username you're connected as.

Try connecting from the command line client with `mysql -u root -p` or whatever username you have instead of root. See if you can show other databases from there.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it was logging in as what looked like a temporary user instead of my username

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin has a stupid feature that hides tables.  There's an eye icon to the right of database or table names.  Click it to toggle the "hidden" attribute.  F'n waste of time!